# A positive integer gets reduced by nine times when one of its digits is deleted and the resultant number is divisible by 9.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, real-numbers

The question says

> A positive integer gets reduced by nine times when one of its digits is deleted and the resultant number is divisible by 9. Prove that to divide the resultant number by 9, it is again sufficient to delete one of its digits. Find all such numbers

I have been stuck on this question for quite some time now. I tried it by taking $$N=a_{n}10^n+a_{n-1}10^{n-1}+....+a_{1}x+a_0$$
I concluded that $N$ is divisible by 81, and that the deleted digit is either 0 or 9. Then I tried solving for $N/9$ but it turned out to be a rather long expression, which I was unable to solve even after a lot of attempts.
 
Kindly help me out in this question.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A positive integer gets reduced by 9 times when one of its digits is deleted....](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1963258/a-positive-integer-gets-reduced-by-9-times-when-one-of-its-digits-is-deleted)

Comment: @DatBoi Actually I could not understand the solution given in the linked question. So I thought of asking a different question mentioning my attempt.